# want to copy from an txt file to another

Tags: linux, shell

Hello i Need a Little help for a shellscript first try.
I have a txt file which has only one line.

example :

MDF;20170724;KT958     ;KT958               ;  14253;          ;            13239611;              240201; K;0885ACBA.PDF;HLN

(all in one line)

So. the numbers and words change all the time, but not the Position of them.
I need only two numbers from a specific place and want to copy them to another NEW File.

Example :

" MDF;20170724;KT958     ;KT958               ;  **14253**;          ;            13239611;              **240201**; K;0885ACBA.PDF;HLN"

i need the in bold shown numbers in a new file.
the new must look as followed :

In first line : 14253
in second line : 240201

thats it.

How can i do this to  say in the script "grab number after semicolon 4 and after semicolon 7 and copy them in file 2 ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it by using awk.

```
awk -F ';' '{print $5"\n"$8}' your_file
```

- `-F ';'` sets the field delimiter to `;`
- `$5` and `$8` are simply the fields you want to print. Add a newline (`\n`) between them.